# Four place names from 12 cryptic clues

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, cryptic-clues

> A1. Steps, Mister? Outside? Thank you (5)
>   A2. Aerial exercise outside, computer network inside (5)
>   A3. Canonized hollow fruit recurring (6)
>
> B1. Light-hearted student at first sent back in the Middle East (5)
>   B2. Tom and his family give captain's head injuries, topless (7)
>   B3. In tax office I blossom (4)
>
> C1. Stunning suit (4)
>   C2. Explorer follows gold pens (6)
>   C3. Reformer reportedly menaces Metropolis (6)
>
> D1. Faux marshes contain radioactive material (5)
>   D2. Not objecting shortly returning award (4)
>   D3. Man removes butt from rifle, briefly asks for reason (3)

Looking for four place names, one for each triplet. Each answer is clued with the same (mysterious) method.

Note: The part of speech required for each answer is listed below. As pointed out in the comments, these don't agree with the definitions in many cases... My bad!

> A1. singular noun
>   A2. singular noun
>   A3. singular noun
>   B1. singular proper noun
>   B2. plural noun
>   B3. singular noun
>   C1.singular noun
>   C2. singular noun
>   C3. singular proper noun
>   D1. adjective
>   D2. singular proper noun
>   D3. singular noun

Comment: Should C2 be PEN instead of PENS?

Comment: Hmm I thought "pens"... as in rot13(gur nafjre vf fbzrbar jub craf fghss)?

Comment: I'm reading it as a verb. So to pen == to (answer).

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Ah I see now, that makes sense.

Comment: A bit of constructive criticism: There are a *lot* of part of speech mismatches here. For instance, "pens" cannot clue the answer to its clue, because the answer is a noun and "pens" is either a verb or a plural noun that doesn't mean the same thing as the noun. C3's "definition" is a description of what the answer does, not a definition. (You cannot define "sun" with "shines", but "thing that shines" would be alright.)

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks for the comments! Still learning to make these, so constructive criticism is definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the method is:

> to remove the letters of the third word, in order, from the first two.

So:

> A: STAIRPLANE - STAPLE = IRAN
>  B: SYRIACRUISES - IRIS = SYRACUSE
>  C: CLUBAUTHOR - LUTHOR = CUBA
>  D: BOGUSTONY - GUY = BOSTON

Comment: This is correct!

Answer (score 7):

Some solutions if it helps anyone:

A2.  Aerial exercise outside, computer network inside (5)

> def= aerial, Exercise= PE outside LAN = **PLANE**

B3. In tax office I blossom (4)

> Def= blossom,  I in IRS = **IRIS**

and a guess:

C1. Stunning suit (4)

> Cryptic def:  **Club**

Answer (score 7):

A couple extra solutions:

D3. Man removes butt from rifle, briefly asks for reason (3)

> **GUY**
> Man = guy
> (Removes butt from rifle = gun - n = **gu**) + (Asks for reason = why, briefly, **y**) = **guy**

D1. Faux marshes contain radioactive material (5)

> **BOGUS**
> Fake = bogus
> (Marshes = **bogs**) containing (radioactive material = Uranium = **U**) = **bogus**

Answer (score 5):

C3.
Reformer reportedly menaces Metropolis (6)

> Menaces Metropolis = Lex **LUTHOR** Reportedly (Homophone) **LUTHER** (Martin Luther, protestant reformer)
>  Hint in comments leads me to believe I have it reversed Answer might be LUTHOR

C2.
Explorer follows gold pens (6)

> **THOR** Heyerdahl follows AU = **AUTHOR**
> NOTE: should clue be pen instead of pens?

With C1 from TwoBitOperation,
C:

> **CLUB AUTHOR LUTHOR**

D2.
Not objecting shortly returning award (4)

> Not Objecting = **Why Not**.  Shortly = YNOT = TONY (award) returned.

So with NudgeNudge's answer, The full clue is

D:

> **BOGUS TONY GUY**

Comment: Ahh, should have put the first two words in reverse order in C3... It's now ambiguous which part the "reportedly" refers to.

Comment: Not necessarily I'm assuming I swapped them?  I wasn't sure about that.  Maybe a comma would fix the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

A1:

> STAIR [SIR outside TA]

A3:

> STAPLE [ST + AP(p)LE]

With A2 from @TwoBitOperation:

A:

> STAIR PLANE STAPLE

B2:

> CRUISES [C(aptain) + (b)RUISES]

B1 (by guessing the final answer):

> SYRIA [S + AIRY<]